# Hive/SQL How do you access the value of the column which you just computed for previous rows?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table `uv_user_date` looks like this:
[image]

Its basically a `user log in table` which shows the cumulative login days partition by user_id.
And the column `pre` show the last login date of a user login record.

Based on this I want to compute the consecutive login days for each user record.

The answer should be :
[image]
My idea is : for a record

- if(uv_date - pre = 1 day)

  - then consecutive login days is the last consecutive login days + 1
- else

  - 1
    but I am having trouble with accessing the `last consecutive login days` value.

The Code would be:

```
SELECT *,
   if(pre = date_add(uv_date, -1), last(consecutive_days) + 1, 1) consecutive_days
FROM uv_user_date
```

Is there any way to get the value of `last(consecutive_days)`

Answer (score 2):

First find date difference

```
tbl1:
select *, 
       if(pre = NULL, 1, datediff(uv_date, pre)) as diff
  from your_table
```

then difference between cumulative sum of difference and accumulative_uv_date for each user_id, you want to use it as rank

```
tbl2:
select *, 
sum(diff) over (partition by user_id order by uv_date rows between unbounded preceding and current) - accumulative_uv_date as rnk
   from tbl1
```

finally, count consecutive days

```
select user_id, uv_date, rnk
row_number() over (partition by user_id, rnk order by uv_date) as consecutive_days
  from tbl2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, thats definitely a good way to do it.